# traverse ancestors in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to determine if a given Angular element is an ancestor of the target Angular element:

```
function isAncestor(element, target) {
    for (var parent = target.parent();
         parent && parent !== element;
         parent = parent.parent()) {
        console.log(parent);
    }
    return parent;
}
```

This goes into an infinite loop. Apparently, `parent` is never `null` as this code assumes. And the equality comparison is incorrect because it checks object references.

How do I do this in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution:

```
function isAncestor(element, target) {
    var parent = target;

    while (parent.length > 0) {
        if (parent[0] === element[0]) {
            return parent;
        }
        parent = parent.parent();
    }
    return null;
}
```